# IFRAME inside a COLUMN RESIZE (HTML)

Tags: html, iframe, html-table

How can I accomplish this?

I have an iframe inside a column (html table), but I want to make the td as high as the doc inside the iframe.

Is it possible?

Comment: Try <td style="height: auto;">

Comment: the td should resize automatically. the problem is the iframe. if you set an explicit height to the iframe it should work. however, you might be in for more work if it has to resize automatically.

Comment: JS is OK.
The td is 100% heigh and also the iframe is the same. The aspx file that is in the iframe is 600px high, but when is loaded in the iframe, it does not resize.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer ( in JQuery).

in jQuery :

```
$("#myIframe").on("load", function ()
{
    $(this).parent("td:first").css('width', $(this).css('width')).css('height', $(this).css('height'))
});
```

Comment: never tryed Jquery, im gonna try it now and lets see what happen

Comment: where do i need to put this piece of code ?, srry as u can see im new to Jquery(i have libraries and all that in my proyect)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the height of the content using Javascript.

You can see a working example here:
http://th.atguy.com/mycode/iframe_size/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this piece of code in 2 projects, it works ok for me. I don't know if there is a better way to achieve this (note that this code has a setInterval, it will check the iframe's content height each 1 second and update its heights). It uses jQuery too.

```
let iframe = document.getElementById('your_iframe_id'),
    current_height = 0,
    iframe_content = $(iframe).contents().find('body');

setInterval(() => {
    let new_height = iframe.contents().find('body').height();
    current_height = new_frame_height(current_height, new_height);
    iframe.css({ height: current_height });
}, 1000)

function new_frame_height(last_height, height) {
    if(height != last_height + 60) {
        last_height = height;
    }
    return last_height + 60
}
```

By the way I think this only works if the iframe is under the same domain from the parent.
If they are not, the cross origin block from the browser will not allow the parent to read the children's content.